# Como puedo acceder a los valores de un json de tipo URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Estoy obteniendo los valores de este json https://swapi.co/api/people/1/ pero, cuando intento obtener "films" me muestra el valor como undefined. Hago referencia a este valor exacto pero creo que no esta reconociendo que es un json y por eso muestra el undefined.

La referencia es a este valor

```
"films": [
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/2/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/6/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/3/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/1/", 
        "https://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
    ],
```

Anexo el código

```js
function get (URL, callback) {
    "use strict";
    
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //Todo ok
        callback(null, JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      } else {
        //Hubo un error
        callback(new Error(`Se produjo un error al realizar el request: ${this.status}`)); //this apunta al request xhttp
      }
    }
  
    xhttp.open('GET', URL); //Type of Request
    xhttp.send(null);  // Send request to server
  }
  

  function handleError(err) {
    console.log(`Request failed: ${err}`);
  }

  get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/', function onResponde(err, luke) {
    if (err) return handleError;
    /*Trae el mundo*/
    get(luke.homeworld, function onHomeWorldResponse (err, homeworld) {
      if (err) return handleError;
      /*Traer la especie*/
      get(luke.species, function onSpeciesResponse (err, species) {
        if (err) return handleError;
        get(luke.films[0], function onFilmsResponse(err, films) {
          if (err) return handleError;
          luke.films[0] = films;
          console.log(`${luke.name} estuvo en las peliculas ${luke.films.title}`);
        })
        luke.species = species;
        console.log(`${luke.name} es un ${luke.species.name}`);
      })
      luke.homeworld = homeworld;
      console.log(`${luke.name} nació en ${luke.homeworld.name}`);
    })
    console.log(`Request succeded`);
    console.log(`luke`, luke);
    console.log("Datos de Sr." + luke.name.substr(0,4) + ":");
    console.log(`Nombre Completo: ${luke.name}
                 Género: ${luke.gender}
                 Estatura: ${luke.height}
                 Color de Cabello: ${luke.hair_color}
                 Color de ojos: ${luke.eye_color}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sale ese error por que haces referencia a una propiedad que no tiene (**title**) lo que debes hacer primero es recuperar cada  film con la función  Get  que haces  de forma iterativa para este caso use un **for** que recupera la informacion y la imprime puede  hacer el cambio para que  solo lo recupere y despues al final concatenar  los nombre de las peliculas.

```js
function get (URL, callback) {
    "use strict";
    
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //Todo ok
        callback(null, JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      } else {
        //Hubo un error
        callback(new Error(`Se produjo un error al realizar el request: ${this.status}`)); //this apunta al request xhttp
      }
    }
  
    xhttp.open('GET', URL); //Type of Request
    xhttp.send(null);  // Send request to server
  }
  

  function handleError(err) {
    console.log(`Request failed: ${err}`);
  }

  get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/', function onResponde(err, luke) {
    if (err) return handleError;
    /*Trae el mundo*/
    get(luke.homeworld, function onHomeWorldResponse (err, homeworld) {
      if (err) return handleError;
      /*Traer la especie*/
      get(luke.species, function onSpeciesResponse (err, species) {
        if (err) return handleError;
       
        for(var i=0;i < luke.films.length ;i++) //for que recupera la informacion 
        get(luke.films[i], function onFilmsResponse(err, films) {
          if (err) return handleError;
          luke.films[i] = films; //recupera la informacion del film y la asigna al index correcto
          
          console.log(`${luke.name} estuvo en las peliculas ${luke.films[i].title}`); // muestra el titulo del film recuperado.si desea obvias esta parte
        })
// En esta linea ya tienes todos los films recuperados 
        luke.species = species;
        console.log(`${luke.name} es un ${luke.species.name}`);
      })
      luke.homeworld = homeworld;
      console.log(`${luke.name} nació en ${luke.homeworld.name}`);
    })
    console.log(`Request succeded`);
    console.log(`luke`, luke);
    console.log("Datos de Sr." + luke.name.substr(0,4) + ":");
    console.log(`Nombre Completo: ${luke.name}
                 Género: ${luke.gender}
                 Estatura: ${luke.height}
                 Color de Cabello: ${luke.hair_color}
                 Color de ojos: ${luke.eye_color}`);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

es `undefined` porque es un array, deberías recorrer el array para obtener todas las películas, pero por el ejemplo creo que quieras obtener el primero.-

entonces debes cambiar

```
console.log(`${luke.name} estuvo en las peliculas ${luke.films.title}`);
```

por

```
console.log(`${luke.name} estuvo en las peliculas ${luke.films[0].title}`);
```

saludos